# Nextjs Error: Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have run into a weird Next.js error for the first time.

So, I started a Next.js app (app router) using the command below:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

Then I started the app in development mode by running the command; `npm run dev`. And when I visited the URL `localhost:3000`, I saw the following error:

```
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
```

[image]

Here is what is logged in my browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant: Missing ActionQueueContext
    at useReducerWithReduxDevtoolsImpl (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/use-reducer-with-devtools.js?2fe90:95:15)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js?4d4a0:186:100)
    at renderWithHooks (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11009:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16761:13)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18345:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20461:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20510:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20585:29)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26763:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25587:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25573:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25529:9)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24382:38)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:261:34)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:230:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:534:21)
useReducerWithReduxDevtoolsImpl @ use-reducer-with-devtools.js:95
Router @ app-router.js:196
renderWithHooks @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:11009
mountIndeterminateComponent @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:16761
beginWork$1 @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:18345
callCallback @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:20461
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:20510
invokeGuardedCallback @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:20585
beginWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:26763
performUnitOfWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25587
workLoopConcurrent @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25573
renderRootConcurrent @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25529
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24382
workLoop @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:261
flushWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:230
performWorkUntilDeadline @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:534
app-index.js:32 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.
window.console.error @ app-index.js:32
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js:45
printWarning @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:94
error @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:68
errorHydratingContainer @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:36087
recoverFromConcurrentError @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24471
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24420
workLoop @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:261
flushWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:230
performWorkUntilDeadline @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:534
use-reducer-with-devtools.js:95 Uncaught Error: Invariant: Missing ActionQueueContext
    at useReducerWithReduxDevtoolsImpl (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/use-reducer-with-devtools.js?2fe90:95:15)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js?4d4a0:186:100)
    at renderWithHooks (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11009:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16761:13)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18345:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20461:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20510:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:20585:29)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26763:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25587:12)
    at workLoopSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25303:5)
    at renderRootSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25258:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24475:20)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24420:26)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:261:34)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:230:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:534:21)
useReducerWithReduxDevtoolsImpl @ use-reducer-with-devtools.js:95
Router @ app-router.js:196
renderWithHooks @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:11009
mountIndeterminateComponent @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:16761
beginWork$1 @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:18345
callCallback @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:20461
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:20510
invokeGuardedCallback @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:20585
beginWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:26763
performUnitOfWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25587
workLoopSync @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25303
renderRootSync @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25258
recoverFromConcurrentError @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24475
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24420
workLoop @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:261
flushWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:230
performWorkUntilDeadline @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:534
app-index.js:32 The above error occurred in the <Router> component:

    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js?4d4a0:169:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js?c44e0:100:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js?c44e0:130:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js?4d4a0:451:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:128:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:144:11)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundaryHandler.
window.console.error @ app-index.js:32
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js:45
logCapturedError @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:15107
update.callback @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:15156
callCallback @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:8194
commitCallbacks @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:8241
commitClassCallbacks @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21219
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21321
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21303
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21303
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21303
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21303
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21303
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21473
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21473
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21473
recursivelyTraverseLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22823
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:21333
commitLayoutEffects @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:22809
commitRootImpl @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:26054
commitRoot @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25907
commitRootWhenReady @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24627
finishConcurrentRender @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24592
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24437
workLoop @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:261
flushWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:230
performWorkUntilDeadline @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:534
auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:16451 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
    at updateHostRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16451:57)
    at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18373:14)
    at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26741:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25587:12)
    at workLoopSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25303:5)
    at renderRootSync (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25258:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24475:20)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24420:26)
    at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:261:34)
    at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:230:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:534:21)
updateHostRoot @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:16451
beginWork$1 @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:18373
beginWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:26741
performUnitOfWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25587
workLoopSync @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25303
renderRootSync @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:25258
recoverFromConcurrentError @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24475
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js|app-pages-browser:24420
workLoop @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:261
flushWork @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:230
performWorkUntilDeadline @ auto|C:\Users\Delhivery\desktop\excelai\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js|app-pages-browser:534
```

Can someone help?

Note: I am on windows and have been developing Next.js app for a long time without any issues. This is the first time I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Was having this on Windows 10 and Next.js 14.0.3 and getting console errors that said `There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.` I switched from using VSCode integrated terminal to cmd in another window and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was folder name casing (just like the error said).
My folder is named `APP`, but I was in `app`.

```bash
projects/app> npm run dev  app runs but throws error
```

```bash
cd ../APP
```

```bash
projects/APP> npm run dev  works correctly
```

Comment: For me it wasn't even the subdirectory.  I had to be case correct all the way through the directory.  For instance I had c:\users when it needed to be c:\Users.  This is my first Next.js app, and that is NOT encouraging!  Thanks for your fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Just check your projects are not created in a folder named Next or next
I faced it just now and seems this was the only problem for above

Answer (score -2):

it works starting the server from cmd not from vscode integrated terminal. but dont know the exact reason

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).